# How to turn a float number like 1.56783 into 1.567 in FreeFem++

Tags: c, floating-point, freefem++

I want to save the number 1.56783 as 1.567 in FreeFem++
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In most programming languages this will work if there is not such rounding function.

```
multiply by 1000
round to the nearest integer
divide by 1000
```

Comment: I tested that, but the results in python and in FreeFem++ are not the same! The last step when you divide by 1000, truncates to different numbers! :(